# Overloading operator []

Tags: c++, matrix, overloading, operator-keyword, brackets

I have a task to write a class matrix in C++ and there is a condition, to override the operator [] for matrix so if I have a matrix with name Matrix with this "Matrix[0][0]" I must take it's first element, on it's first line. I have represented the matrix with two dimensional dynamic array and templates (T **matrix). Could you help me, please?

PS: This method I'm using to create the two dimensional array:

```
template <class T>
T ** Matrix<T>::createMatrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols)
{
    T** matrix = new T*[rows];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        matrix[i] = new T[cols];

    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: `T**` does **not** describe a two dimensional array. It describes an array of arrays, which is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume matrix is a member variable of type T** of Matrix.

```
template< class T >
T* operator []( Matrix<T>& m, unsigned int row )
{
  // maybe remember rows and assert(row<rows);
  return m.matrix[ row ];
}
```

Now you may write something like

```
Matrix<T> m(50,9999);
m[42][1337];
```

to access element 1337 in row 42.

Comment: Thank you! Very simple, clever and elegant! Thank you again:).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two classes. The matrix class overrides [] and returns a row object. The row object overrides [] and returns a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is return a T* in operator[], as it can then have operator[] applied to it natively and get the result that you want. However, I want to point out that it's pretty bad practice to leave your pointers raw.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that natively in C++, but you could simply instanciate your matrix this way:

```
Matrix<Matrix<int>> m;
```

This way the first [ ] returns another matrix which will return the item you want. Of course a much better name for your class then would be Vector, and a wrapper class called Matrix  that creates an internal `Vector<Vector<T>>`.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using to create the matrix doesn't have anything to do with a class, as your requirements state. You are creating a simple `T**`, it doesn't make a difference that you are doing it in a class method.

Creating a matrix of `T` that can be used as in `matrix[i][j]` means that the expression `matrix[i]` must return a type on which operator `[]` is also defined to return a `T`. Therefore, the usual way to do it is break it down in steps:

- `Matrix<T> operator[] (int)` returns a `MatrixRow<T>&`
- `MatrixRow<T>& operator[] (int)` returns a `T&`

There will also be `const` versions of these operators to be used when reading values from the matrix (non-const versions will be used when writing to the matrix).

So, at the minimum, you should create a class with this interface:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
    public:
        Matrix(int rows, int cols);

        const MatrixRow<T>& operator[] (int row) const;
        MatrixRow<T>& operator[] (int row);
}
```

PS: This reads like a homework question, is it one?

Comment: Yes it is. I done the determinant method, multiplication method and so on...Now at last I done this :).